# CSS error : Name of overqualified element should be removed

Tags: html, css, csslint

Consider this css, which make all elements in `form` and with `mask-amount` class become bold:

```
form .mask-amount {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Of course the above will not change the font weight of `mask-amount` elements outside form.

```
This will not be bold <span class="mask-amount">123,456</span>
<form>
   This will be bold <span class="mask-amount">123,456</span>
</form>
```

Code At: http://jsfiddle.net/a9qt8jw7/

However when I review my css with Sonar, I get this error  **Name of overqualified element should be removed**. The error described at https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-overqualified-elements In brief

> Writing selectors such as li.active are unnecessary unless the element
>   name causes the class to behave differently. In most cases, it's safe
>   to remove the element name from the selector, both reducing the size
>   of the CSS as well as improving the selector performance (doesn't have
>   to match the element anymore).

I don't want the other elements with `mask-amount` class be bold and so I cannot simply remove the `form` from css selector.

I used this kind of selectors a lot. I want to know what is the best way to change my css and fix this error. (I can not change my htmls, this will be a HUGE task!!)

Comment: The rule seems to cover elements like `form.mask-amount` not `form .mask-amount` (notice the missing space in the first example). Are you sure it's triggered because of this exact css rule? Maybe it's targeting another css rule?

Comment: Yes it is: `form .mask-amount` cut and pasted

Comment: Probably Sonar checks if there are any occurencies of `.mask-amount` outside your form. And perhaps in that particular page there are none (making the `form` useless in the scope of that page). But, since your CSS applies to other pages too, either teach Sonar about those pages, either use it more as a guide, not to the letter. The rule above is **rock solid**. No downsides. You worry too much.